# How to remove font tag which is added automatically when we translate the page with help of google translate script

Tags: google-translate

The font tag automatically added when we translate the page with the help of google translate script.

Below image shows the original code :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDyCU.png)

The font tag automatically added when we translate the page with the help of google translate script.

I want to remove that font tag which is added by google translate script.

Below image shows the font tag automatically added by google translate [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMywn.png):

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that `font` tag by using Javascript.

The script will remove all the font tags and it will remove the tag and add the content inside the tag.

```
function removeFontTag() { 
   const fontTags = document.querySelectorAll('font');
   console.log(fontTags);
   fontTags.forEach((font) => {
      const text = font.innerText;
      const fontParent = font.parentElement;

     font.outerHTML = text;
   });
}

removeFontTag();
```